# Excel: Drop down list with dependent length changes reference spontaneously

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

In an excel file I am using a drop down list with variable length dependent on a user selection. The length is given by following formula that counts all the rows in the list and offers a drop down containing all the values in it.

```
=SQL_Structure!T5:INDEX(SQL_Structure!$T:$T,COUNTA(SQL_Structure!$T:$T)+3)
```

When I save and close the reference in the name manager, the formula spontaneously changes to the different cell instead of reference to cell T5. The modification is seemingly random. I tried several times and the cell reference differed each time. When I run the macro that modifies the list the reference is lost completely as below.

```
=SQL_Structure!#REF:INDEX(SQL_Structure!$T:$T,COUNTA(SQL_Structure!$T:$T)+3)
```

Any idea on what might be causing it?

Answer (score 0):

It should be good. Try like: SQL_Structure!$T$5

Almantas

Comment: Hi Almantas,Thank you. Fixing the cell works until I run the macro that modifies the content of table the cell T5 belongs into. I have found that once the data in the table are renewed the formula breaks. Now I was able to think of 2 solutions: 1. To start indexing the cell above which works but includes also the header in the list. That I would like o avoid. 2. To format the data not as a table. That is also not optimal as the table format is essential for other macro I run in the report.